# Automatic KDE Plasma scaling based on monitor in use

Tags: kubuntu, display, kde, display-resolution

I'm a total Linux noobie, and would appreciate some pointers as to, hopefully, setting up automatic scaling of KDE Plasma based on the resolution of the monitor in use.

I've managed to install a fully portable Kubuntu 20.04 system onto an external SSD, which I use at home on a Surface Pro 4 and at work on a Sony Vaio laptop. The screen of the former, according to xrandr output is eDP-1 with 2736x1824 resolution, while the later is LVDS-1 with a resolution of 1366x768.
Now, on the laptop, with the global scale set to 100% (in System Settings > Display Configuration), everything looks great. On the SP4, I have to set the scaling to 175% or 200%, otherwise everything looks too tiny to do any work.
I change the scaling manually, based on where I'm using the system, but, using it on a daily basis for the past month or so, it's becoming tedious (booting, changing the scaling, logging out and back in).

I've done a lot of "googling" into this, and tried adding the following:

```
[KSCREEN]
ScaleFactor=1 
ScreenScaleFactors=LVDS-1=1;VGA-1=1,DVI-1=1.75;HDMI-1=1.75;DP-1=1.75;eDP-1=1.75;
```

to kdeglobals in /root/.config (as well as in /root/.kde/share/config/), but it's had no effect whatsoever.

I did find some information indicating I could possible use xrandr for this purpose, but it's all been beyond my level of understanding.

There's also the matter of using an external monitor with a different resolution on the SP4, and the 200% scaling being too large on the external display. Windows 10 handles this perfectly, with different scaling on the native screen and the external monitor, but I've gathered that it's impossible to do on Linux, except maybe with Wayland. Speaking of which, I've installed it, but the Plasma Wayland session is buggy, with some applications not working properly...

In any case, does anybody have any pointers, solutions actually, for setting up automatic scaling (ignoring the external monitor bit)?

::edit :: October 12::

I figured I can achieve something similar to what I asked by inputting

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 0.7x0.7
```

in the terminal (or setting up a script to run this command at boot). Unfortunately, with the use of this command, everything on the screen is slightly blurry. Also, Firefox doesn't seem to scale properly with this command, it just looks odd, like it's been scaled halfway...

So, again, does anybody know if it's actually possible to automate KDE Plasma scaling in any way, by use of a script or something?
Or if I'm doing something incorrectly with the kdeglobals file?